# On Firebase Auth console, is it normal to have an empty e-mail when logging in with Twitter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-login

So after some hours following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login) tutorial I was able to implement Twitter login into my app.

The problem is that now I have this into my Firebase Auth console:

[image]

As you can see I was able to log in with Twitter, but the e-mail is empty.
I think maybe this has something to do with the fact [that](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html)

> Request User Email Address
>
> !Note
>
> Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

So If Twitter doesn't allow as standard to get the user e-mail, Firebase  wouldn't know the e-mail address, that's why the login e-mail is empty.

Is this correct? If then I want to get the user e-mail and register it on my Firebase Auth console I have to request this permission to Twitter?

Comment: You have to whitelist your Twitter app to allow disclosure of emails. Twitter does not return emails by default in their OAuth response.

Comment: I sent to Twitter a request to do that last week. Still awaiting for the reply...